# Is there a way to send a Twilio SMS with React on the Client Side?

Tags: reactjs, twilio

Is there a way to send a Twilio SMS with React on the Client Side? If not, how can I send a Twilio SMS with JS?

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

const twilio = require("twilio");

// Find your account sid and auth token in your Twilio account Console.
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

export const sendSMS = (to, body) => {
  // Send the text message.
  client.messages.create({
    to: to,
    from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
    body: body,
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you know any other Twilio Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

No, because it would mean exposing your auth token on the client side where everybody could read it.

But there's an alternative if you say you don't want/need a backend. You can use [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets) to implement the code to send the SMS and [protect the Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/json-web-token) either with a JWT token or (for testing) basic auth.